# $ regex replace equivalent in python

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I'm writing a python program that uses `re.sub`
`re.sub("( |\t)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) = ", "$1\"$2\":", string)`
the only issue is that when I use this code instead of actually using the groups via the $s it writes down `$1"$2":`. In js and even in the [visual studio code find and replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5skE1.png) it works so what would be the equivalent?

I've tried searching for an answer and only gotten results that line up with the regex match of "at end of line" `$`.

Comment: It's called the [`\number` special sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as in `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are trying to do it will not work either. The structure `$n` python did not know. You have to specify a function for the replacement, which takes a regex match object as argument with which then the groups are evaluated. In your example like this:

```py
import re

string = ""

def replace_func(matches):
    return f'{matches.group(1)}"{matches.group(2)}":'

re.sub("( |\t)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) = ", replace_func, string)
```